# Why is "Save as" option is missing in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Why isnt there a simple save-as option in IntelliJ IDEA? Is there a way to easily save as a file?

Comment: Wow, it's missing for at least 12 years now - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-17537

Answer (score 3):

In my experience looking for alternate ways of performing simple tasks like **Save as** is both annoying and time-consuming, and **Refactor** | **Copy** is not a very intuitive alternative.

Answer (score 2):

**Save as** is essentially the same as making a copy of the file under the different name. IntelliJ IDEA copy operation is provided via the **refactoring**, so you can use `Refactor` | **Copy** (<kbd>F5</kbd>) instead of Save as.

Comment: You can use refactoring to copy and move the files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `Refactor -> Copy...`. This creates a new .java file and rename the class name for you if the file is Java source code, otherwise simply duplicate the current file under a new name.

Comment: This is not the same.  I started editing a JSP and then realized it breaks some existing functionality.  So I wanted to save it under a new name instead, leaving the original file unmodified.  Refactor -> Copy doesn't do that.  I don't think people use "save as" to make a copy without making any change at the same time.

Comment: Noone mentioned .java files at all. I'm missing this option when editing a txt file where I need a similar file - I normally make a change, do Save As and then undo the change in the original file. With Refactor - it's impossible (undo will attempt to undo 'refactoring'), and also - it's not right to call text edits - refactorings.

Comment: all refactor->copy does is make a new file with the same contents. there shouldn't be any editing. that's the same as save-as.

Answer (score 0):

**Short direct answer:**

Press `F5` and write new name of new class.

**Not direct answer with question:**

You should think carefully - why do you want to duplicate code?

Probably it's better to extract "future" common code to separated class and use it in your old and new classes.

Comment: One reason is to save a scratch file somewhere useable